# Android WebView stays blank

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to Android and I started with a basic app (chose API 5.1 / created virtual device 5.1.1/API22 because that's what I'll later be using in reality) that only contains a WebView:

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

However, whatever I do in my Activity's Java code, the page stays blank. I tried many tipps from SO etc., but nothing worked, so it must be something very basic I'm missing?

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package de.jstest.notes;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); // is this actually needed?
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String summary = "<html><head><title>WebView JS Tester</title></head><body>" +
                "Code<br>" +
                "<textarea id='code'></textarea><br>" +
                "Result<br>" +
                "<textarea id='result'></textarea><br>" +
                "<input type='button' value='Eval' onclick='" +
                "document.getElementById(\"result\").value=eval(document.getElementById(\"code\").value)" +
                "'>" +
                "</body></html>";
        myWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("WebView 'title' = " + myWebView.getTitle());
        builder.setPositiveButton("Now try a web page...",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.de/");
                    dialog.dismiss(); // otherwise, dialog stays open
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Also, the *dialog (button) doesn't work* (neither my code above, nor the more basic approach setting the click handler directly), i.e., the app opens (sometimes *with*, sometimes *without* its heading "Notes"...), and as described the WebView remains blank; I see the dialog (saying that the web view `title` is empty), but clicking on the one button ("Now try a web page...") *has no effect at all*. After several clicks I'm asked if I want to close the non-responding app...

Note that both the `loadData` and the `loadUrl` result in a blank page. For the latter to work, I tried

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but that didn't change anything here.

Comment: the `loadData` part seems to be working OK here...my version of it (sorry convoluted)   777e28a https://github.com/rdp/sensible-cinema

Comment: Thank you! I will try it tonight and give feedback.